# How can I avoid autorepeated keydown events in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

If the user holds down the key, multiple keydown events are fired. For usability reasons I need to use keydown, not keyup, but I want to avoid this situation. My relevant code is the following:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) { 
        var key = 0;


        if (e == null) { key = event.keyCode;}  
        else {  key = e.which;} 


        switch(key) {
            case config.keys.left:                
              goLeft();
              break;
            case config.keys.up:                        
              goUp();
              break;
            case config.keys.right:                     
              goRight();
              break;
            case config.keys.down:                
              goDown();
              break;
            case config.keys.action:              
              select();
              break;
        }     
      });
```

So when the user holds down the down key, for example, goDown() is fired multiple times. I would like it to fire just once even if the user holds the key down.

Comment: You don't need the if statement. jQuery normalizes the events object so `e.keyCode` or `e.which` (either one) is safe...

Comment: What if the user pressed the same key twice in a row so fast that it appears to be one single key hold. (Like in Minority Report, when the girl sees a different murder but they think it's an echo of a past murder because it resembles it so much.)

Comment: @sime thanks for the tip, I didnt know that. Re: pressing the same key twice, it should detect that they are two different keystrokes, it shouldnt be a problem

Comment: Should the application be able to process two simultaneous key presses (key combos) or two key presses that overlap?

Comment: Not really. It's just a keyboard navigation functionality, and except for this problem, it works fine as it is, even with simulateneous key presses

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use `event.repeat` to detect whether or not the event is repeating. You could then wait for "keyup" before allowing the handler to execute a second time.

```
var allowed = true;

$(document).keydown(function(event) { 
  if (event.repeat != undefined) {
    allowed = !event.repeat;
  }
  if (!allowed) return;
  allowed = false;
  //...
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) { 
  allowed = true;
});
$(document).focus(function(e) { 
  allowed = true;
});
```

Comment: @agente_secreto What if I pressed 2 buttons then release only one of them? Then the event for the button that is already pressed will be fired that is incorrect.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the test was `event.originalEvent.repeat` but it works perfectly. Using jQuery version `1.8.3`

Comment: this worked great for me, however I needed to add a quick `event.preventDefault()` to the end, otherwise I'd get weird click events firing from my mouse click event.

Comment: I really don't understand the need for the `allowed` variable. If you want the event to only happen once, you can just use `if (event.repeat) return;` at the beginning of the function. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/SamyBencherif/3j679pzd/14/)

Comment: What are we supposed to use now as event is deprecated?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! (In fact it's the ONLY solution that has worked.)

Answer (score 8):

Another simple adjustment to the accepted answer to allow for the multiple keys scenario:

```
var keyAllowed = {};

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (keyAllowed [e.which] === false) return;
  keyAllowed [e.which] = false;
  // code to be executed goes here
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) { 
  keyAllowed [e.which] = true;
});

$(document).focus(function(e) { 
  keyAllowed = {};
});
```

Answer (score 6):

its simple

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.repeat) return;
    // ...
});
```

Comment: What! I can only assume that previous versions of browsers did not implement the `repeat` attribute correctly, otherwise all the previous answers are just over-complex. Just use this one for modern webware.

Answer (score 3):

So, if the existing solution seems dubious (it doesn't consider the case when 2 or more buttons is pressed simultaneously), I suggest another solution that takes it into account.

The **_prevKeyDown** object is to store keys that are currently pressed.

```
    _prevKeyDown = {}

    function _downKey( event )
    {
        var wh = event.which;
        var kC = event.keyCode;

        if( _prevKeyDown[ wh ] == null )
        {
            _prevKeyDown[ wh ] = {};
        }

        _prevKeyDown[ wh ][ kC ] = true;
    };

    function _upKey( event )
    {
        var wh = event.which;
        var kC = event.keyCode;

        if( _prevKeyDown[ wh ] != null )
        {
            _prevKeyDown[ wh ][ kC ] = null;
        }               
    };

    function _isKeyDown( event )
    {
        var wh = event.which;
        var kC = event.keyCode;

        var result = false;

        if( this._prevKeyDown[ wh ] != null )
        {
            if( this._prevKeyDown[ wh ][ kC ] == true )
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    // now your keydown/keyup handlers
    function keydown( event )
    {
        if( !_isKeyDown( event ) )
        {
            // your once-keydown handler here
            _downKey( event );
        }    
    }

    function keyup( event )
    {
        _upKey( event );
    }
```

Comment: You want a `var` on `_prevKeyDown`, as the code above falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) without it.

Comment: I don't see any point to combining `which` and `keyCode`. You'll get one or the other, depending on the browser, and you only need one of them. And actually, with jQuery (the OP's using jQuery), you only need `which`; it normalizes things.

Answer (score 0):

(Copied from another question which turned out to be a duplicate of this one.)

dmaurolizer's [KeyPress library](https://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/) gives fine control over all keyboard events.  You provide callback functions for events.  The `keydown` event sends an optional `isRepeat` param so you can ignore auto-repeats.  Here's a sample using that functionality for the thrust control in a video game:

```
var my_combos = listener.register_many([
    {
        "keys"          : "up",
        "on_keydown"    : function(e, num, isRepeat) {
            if (isRepeat) return ;
            thrust = 0.1;
        },
        "on_keyup"      : function() {
            thrust = 0;
        }
    }
]);
```