# Why 'keydown' event works like 'keypress' event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The next sample code outputs 'keydown' message many times while I hold a button down. The docs [says](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) that the keydown event happens once for one push of the button. So, the keydown event works like the keypress event in the next example.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title></title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    function onLoad()
    {
        $( '#text' ).on( 'keydown', function() { console.info( 'keydown' ) } ); 
    }   
  </script>

  </head>
  <body onload='onLoad()'>
     <input type='text' id='text'>

  </body>
</html>
```

I tested it on Windows, Firefox 19.0.2 and Google Chrome 25.0.1364.152. Also I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Jxcq/) (the problem can be reproduced). JQuery versions for which problem is reproduced: 1.8.2, 1.9.1.

Update.

I did realize the problem: [How can I avoid autorepeated keydown events in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686197/how-can-i-avoid-autorepeated-keydown-events-in-javascript).

Comment: What do you mean by `'keydown' event works like 'keypress' event?` ?

Comment: When you hold a keyboard button, It fires a push event for each new character that it writes because it's considered a new `keypress`.

Comment: @Sarfraz I thank that a keydown event is fired only once when I push a button. E.g. a KeyUp event is fired only once when I release a button, and I thank that it is only for the fact of the pushing the button.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> The `keydown` event occurs when the key is pressed, followed immediately by the `keypress` event. Then the `keyup` event is generated when the key is released.
>
> In order to understand the difference between `keydown` and `keypress`, it is useful to understand the difference between a "character" and a "key". A "key" is a physical button on the computer's keyboard while a "character" is a symbol typed by pressing a button.  In theory, the `keydown` and `keyup` events represent keys being pressed or released, while the `keypress` event represents a character being typed. The implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers.

Comment: I just wanted to add that keyup and key down fire exactly once per press, keypress will fire repeatedly while the key remains pressed.

Comment: @JesseEarle We've just figured out that keydown will fire repeatedly too.

Comment: FYI the reference above now links to a spam site.

Comment: Whatever it says, but in reality keydown event is followed immediately by  keydown events

Answer (score 11):

The KeyPress event is not raised by noncharacter keys; however, the noncharacter keys do raise the KeyDown and KeyUp events.

Key events occur in the following order:

1. KeyDown
2. KeyPress
3. KeyUp

[Are these events available on the Window, Document, Form, focusable elements](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)
[Test Page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/keys.html)

Answer (score 1):

The keydown event occurs when the key is pressed, followed immediately by the keypress event.

Answer (score 1):

i have answer here, following me slowly:
`keydown` : working when you start typing key or start to change something and keydown give you one result for one press but give you the result before the last one not last result.
`keyup`: working when you stop typing a key or go back (change something like remove character) and it's give give you last result.
`keypress`: working when you start typing key but not start to change something and keydpress give you one result for one press but give you the result before the last ,which (lastResult - 1)