# Are there any benefit to using both keyup and keydown (or keypress) to detect what key the user has pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a basic search app and on keypress in the search input textbox I want to go back to the server to get results for a javascript autosuggestion dropdown. Is there any value to adding event handlers for both keyup and keydown? It seems like the keydown seems to work fine. Also, I noticed there is a keypress event as well. Should I be using that instead?

Comment: The accepted answer here looks promising:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310647/why-keydown-event-works-like-keypress-event

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a simple search input to fire events every keyup and keydown. This would not be very efficient, you also would be making a bunch of unnecessary calls to the server. I would definitely suggest using one or the other. I prefer keyup so that the user may finish typing there letter before the event is fired. So if you are not using the others for a specific reason use KEYUP for a search input.