# Focus on textbox with property TextMode="MultiLine" for enter key press

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In a ASP website i want to navigate between textbox using enter keys so that when i press enter key the focus should go for next textbox.

What I did is in asptextbox used onkeypress function as shown below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" onkeypress="return EnterEvent(event);"></asp:TextBox>
```

And in javascript

```
          function EnterEvent(e) {

              if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                  document.getElementById("Textbox2").focus();
                  }
              }          
</script>
```

It works fine. But in case Textbox2 is a multiline textbox(if i use TextMode="MultiLine" for a asp textbox) then focus will be placed on Textbox2 but it will be placed one extra line below in textbox(focus placed in 2 nd line of multiline textbox). How it can be solved?

Comment: Wild guess but have you tried putting `event.preventDefault()` in your function?

Answer (score 1):

Try this script for enter key navigation through controls..

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        var inputs = $(':input,select').keydown(function (e) {

            if (e.which == 13) {
                if (e.target.id == '') {
                    return;
                }
                e.preventDefault();
                var nextInput = inputs.get(inputs.index(this) + 1);
                if (nextInput) {
                    nextInput.focus();
                    nextInput.select();
                }

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

If the above script is not suitable for your case you can just try changing `onkeypress` to `onkeydown`..You can either use take any one of the cases,not both at a time..

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" onkeydown="return EnterEvent(event);"></asp:TextBox>
```

You can understand the difference between keydown and keypress by refering the link below..

[Difference between Keypress and keydown...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310647/why-keydown-event-works-like-keypress-event)

Comment: I didnt understand the script.Where this function to be called?

Comment: You just add this in your page..This function will be called in every synchronous and asynchronous postbacks..It checks the key pressed inside any input control other than Dropdownlist and if it is Enter key it will navigate to the next input control..No need of writing javascript functions on each control to navigate to the next control,Regards...

Comment: I think it will be loaded directly.It does not work in IE6. It works in chrome normally,but incase the asp textbox has a validator like RequiredFieldValidator,RangeValidator then it does not work for me in chrome.

Comment: You still didn't clear my doubt. in ur anser you are showing onkeydown="return EnterEvent(event); and showing pageLoad function. So where to call it?? or where to call EnterEvent?? I m confused

Comment: Sry,friend..my mistake..Either you can use the first script or you can change your code itself from keypress to keydowm..Keypress event cannot identify the keycode of the key pressed,regards..

Comment: "Keypress event cannot identify the keycode of the key pressed" is that really true? In my question i hav mentioned that it worked for textbox without multiline. Also when i use keypress event it worked for textbox. So how is it possible?

Comment: You can read the answer of this question for further clarifications...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310647/why-keydown-event-works-like-keypress-event

Comment: I have tested your same code by changing keypress to keydown and it is working fine on multiline textboxes,Regards..

Comment: I tested after changing keypress to keydown and it places cursor on second line of multiline textbox.I used same script which i mentioned in my question.Only change is onkeydown.

Comment: Just now i created new asp webpage for testing and found that it worked for chrome,but in IE6 cursor focus on second line of multiline textbox.(both keypress and keydown). Then i tested the same for my original page which had so many other javascript too. in this i got error in chrome and IE. so i think some other script causing this problem. I think in chrome when u press enter key page gets post back which gives the problem. And in IE6 the error exists even for a simple page.