# recieving two enters when handling enter keypress event

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make the cursor jump on codebar or manual code input to the next field according to some rules (next field is not necessarly the next in order...)

the function is triggered pressing enter (the end of the codebar also gives me the enter i need).

Trouble is when submitting only one enter keypress (one manual or one with the codebar) the function works as if it got a second one during its execution...
it will re-evaluate which input is active.
I even inserted some alert messages and noticed it really runs twice!

Unable to figure it out I rewrote the code from scratch using a different approach but the result is the same . same error.

I've tried e.preventdefault() also but that was not it.

here are the two versions of the code:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var focado = document.getElementById(document.activeElement.id);
        var fim = focado.id.substring(1);
        var inicio = focado.id.substring(0, 1);

        var anterior = inicio + (fim - 1);

        switch (fim) {
            case "1":
                fimseg = "2"
            case "2":
                fimseg = "3"
            case "3":
                fimseg = "4"
            case "4":
                fimseg = "5"
        }
                    var seguinte = inicio + (fimseg);

                    if (seguinte == "p5") {
                          seguinte = "a1";
                    }

        if (focado.value.length == 0) {

            if (fim != 1) {

                document.getElementById(focado.id).focus()
            } else {

                if (anterior.value.length == 0) {

                    document.getElementById(anterior).focus()
                } else {

                    if (seguinte == "a5") {

                        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
                    } else {

                        document.getElementById(seguinte).focus()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {

            if (focado.value.length < 7 || (isNaN(focado.value))) {

                document.getElementById(focado.id).innerHtml = "";
                if (anterior.value.length == 0) {

                    document.getElementById(anterior).focus()
                } else {

                    document.getElementById(focado).focus()
                }
            } else {

                if (fim != 1) { //não é p1 nem a1


                    if (anterior.value.length == 0) {

                        document.getElementById(anterior).focus()
                    } else {

                        if (seguinte == "a5") {

                            document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
                        } else {

                            document.getElementById(seguinte).focus()
                        }
                    }
                } else {


                    document.getElementById(seguinte).focus()
                }
            }
        }
    } //não é enter
}); //fim função
```

and the another version that has the same error

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
if (e.which == 13) {

    var focado  = document.getElementById(document.activeElement.id);

    if (focado.value.length >= 7) {

        switch (focado.id) {

            case "p4":

                document.getElementById("a1").focus();
                break;

            case "p3":
                document.getElementById("p4").focus();
                break;

            case "p2":
                document.getElementById("p3").focus();
                break;

            case "p1":

                document.getElementById("p2").focus();

        }

    } else {//menos de 7 algarismos

        var fim = focado.id.substring(1);
        var inicio = focado.id.substring(0, 1);
        var anterior = inicio + (fim - 1);

        if (fim != 1) {//não é p1 nem a1

            if (focado.value.length == 0) {//em branco




                if (document.getElementById(anterior).value.length == 0) {//se anterior em branco

                    document.getElementById(anterior).focus();//então foca no anterior - devia haver um get focus sempre que fosse num vazio ia para o anterior
                } else {//anterior com dados
                    if (document.getElementById(anterior).value.length >= 7) {

                        switch (inicio) {
                            case "p"://se anterior com dados é p1
                                document.getElementById("a1").focus();

                                break;

                            case "a"://se anterior com dados é a1
                                document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
                                break;
                        }//final switch

                    } else {//se anterior tem menos de 7 algarismos
                        document.getElementById(anterior).value = "";
                        document.getElementById(anterior).focus();

                    }



                }



            }//final se focado em branco

        }//final não é p1 nem a1

    }//final menos de 7 algarismos

}//não é enter

});
```

maybe catching enter with a different keycode or a different eventhandler?
thanks

UPDATE:
inputboxes are: "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4" and there is a "btnSubmit" button

Comment: when the enter is fired when p1 is active it should jump the focus to p2.
then if a second enter is fired in p2 with p2 empty the focus should jump to a1.
What happens is that the code runs correctly according to a enter fired in p1 and focus on p2 but immediatly refocus on a1 as if a second enter was fired.
on the second code it evaluates the first if as true with length >=7 and identifies the focus as p1 and refocusing on p2 but also proceeds inside the else statement (<7)  and identifies the active element as being p2 and refocusing on a1. It's as if the focus I ordered also fires the enter

Answer (score 0):

You might find using `keyDown` will work better. It's designed to only fire once. `keyPressed` may repeat.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15310690/962289

Also, not sure from your question, but if you have `$(document).keypress` in two different places it should run both of them. Are you sure they aren't interfering with each other?

Comment: with keydown the problem remains.

there is only one code. I posted two versions that have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a few errors on my code.

this way it works:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var focado = document.getElementById(document.activeElement.id);
        var fim = focado.id.substring(1);
        var inicio = focado.id.substring(0, 1);
        var fimseg = fim;
        var anterior = inicio + (fim - 1);

        switch (fim) {
            case "1":
                fimseg = "2"
                break;
            case "2":
                fimseg = "3"
                break;
            case "3":
                fimseg = "4"
                break;
            case "4":
                fimseg = "5"
                break;
        }
        var seguinte = inicio + (fimseg);

        if (seguinte == "p5") {
            seguinte = "a1";
        }

        if (focado.value.length == 0) {

            if (fim != 1) {

                document.getElementById(focado.id).focus()
            } else {

                if (document.getElementById(anterior).value.length == 0) {

                    document.getElementById(anterior).focus()
                } else {

                    if (seguinte == "a5") {

                        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
                    } else {

                        document.getElementById(seguinte).focus()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
                            if (focado.value.length < 7 || (isNaN(focado.value))) {

                document.getElementById(focado.id).innerHtml = "";
                if (anterior.value.length == 0) {

                    document.getElementById(anterior).focus()
                } else {

                    document.getElementById(focado.id).focus()
                }
            } else {

                if (fim != 1) { //não é p1 nem a1


                    if (document.getElementById(anterior).value.length ==0) {

                        document.getElementById(anterior).focus()
                    } else {

                        if (seguinte == "a5") {

                            document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
                        } else {

                            document.getElementById(seguinte).focus()

                        }
                    }
                } else {

                    document.getElementById(seguinte).focus()

                }
            }
        }
    } //não é enter
}); //fim função
```