# Command shortcuts via keypress or keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am seeking advise from others who have experience with creating keyboard shortcuts for productivity web apps.

At the moment, I am linking all my commands to keyup event however I have read posts on the SO that seem to suggest I should link them up to keypress event. I chose key up because I wanted the command be triggered only once instead of multiple times which can happen in the case of keypress. However I am not sure if there is something else that I am missing.

So which event do you recommend for creating command shortcuts for web apps? Keyup or Keypress?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using [`accesskey` attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#the-accesskey-attribute)?

Comment: I wasn't aware of this attribute to be perfectly honest. However after reading how to use it on http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp, I am amazed how messy and non-standardized it is. Can you imagine having to recite Alt + access key on Chrome and Alt + Shift + access key on Firefox? It seems like a huge pain to me as a developer, so I can barely imagine how bad it would be for my customers who are non-technical at all.

Comment: @RowlandShaw I apologize if my comment seemed harsh.

Comment: See: [How can I avoid autorepeated keydown events in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686197/how-can-i-avoid-autorepeated-keydown-events-in-javascript)

Comment: @RowlandShaw have you ever used `accesskey` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. The major difference between `keyup` and `keypress` is that `keypress` is dispatched only when you press some **printable** keys. For example, pressing <kbd>P</kbd> will fire both, but pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> will not fire `keypress`. So in practice, if you define hotkeys involve **unprintable** keys, `keyup` event is the way to go.
2. `accesskey` is standardized in W3C specs. It's not really painful, and a non-technical customer isn't likely to switch between different browsers frequently.
3. Unless developing some complicated web apps, my choice would always be `accesskey`, for a very important reason - **accessibility**. `accesskey` is well supported by common assistive devices, e.g. screen reader. If you use keyboard event to do that, you'll have to do a lot of dirty work for the devices.