# Is it necessary to null an onkeydown method?

Tags: javascript, iframe, null, onkeydown

My code (seen below) seems to work properly, however, I have been reading (e.g. in [How can I avoid autorepeated keydown events in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686197/how-can-i-avoid-autorepeated-keydown-events-in-javascript)) that in some instances, onkeydown() method needs to be nulled.   Why is this?

The intent of this code is to listen for a left or right arrow press (on the index file) and send a function to an iframe, which then forwards another function to another embedded iframe.  There was probably a better way to do this, any input?

```
//Arrow key functionality   
document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

e = e || window.event;

if (e.keyCode == '39') {
// right arrow
    document.getElementById('CENTER').contentWindow.fwdFrame(); 
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
// left arrow
    document.getElementById('CENTER').contentWindow.bkFrame();
    }
}
```

The iframe ('CENTER') has the following code:

```
//Arrow Key Functionality - Forwarded from Index
function fwdFrame() {
   document.getElementById('CONTROL').contentWindow.GoNext();
}

function bkFrame() {
   document.getElementById('CONTROL').contentWindow.GoBack();
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Don't understand the question. If you assign `null` to `document.onkeydown` then this will stop working.

Comment: Is the code working or not? If not, explain the problem, don't just ask a vague question about nulling the method. And if you've read that you need to do this, provide links, maybe there's some context that's relevant.

Comment: I see, so there is no reason to assign a null to this function?  I have read to assign null so as to not create a loop?

Comment: Why would there be a loop? Where did you read that you need to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about returning `false` from the function, to prevent the default action? You can also do that by calling `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686197/how-can-i-avoid-autorepeated-keydown-events-in-javascript

This is a reference, if the key is "held" down, my apologies for not clarifying.

Comment: That issue is not regarding a loop, but the fact that the keyboard will send keydown events continuously (every 200ms or so, depending on settings) while the key is held down. If you don't want the function to continuously execute, you can simply add `if ( e.repeat ) return;` near the top. [See MDN for repeat info.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat)

Comment: Great thank you for explaining that Vox!

Comment: There's nothing in that question about nulling the event handler. And the accepted answer says to check `e.repeat`. So we're back to wondering what your question is really about.

Comment: Barmar, I think Vox did a good good clarifying and responding, not that I can say the same for you with your aggressive methods.   Consider this answered.