# *EDITED WITH A SOLUTION* Stopwatch reactive Shinyapp; *How to Ignore Repeat Keys*

Tags: r, shiny

*Edit* Look to bottom to find my code that solved my problem.  [How can I avoid autorepeated keydown events in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686197/how-can-i-avoid-autorepeated-keydown-events-in-javascript)

I am attempting to build a stopwatch Shiny app.

My end goal is to record "trial" times. Each trial will start when the space bar (key code == 32) is pressed, and will end when the space bar is released. I also want to record the time between my trials, which is time from when the space bar is released to when the space bar is pressed again.

I'd like to get the stopwatch to run continuously when the app is open. However, I want the stopwatch to reset to 0 when I press the space bar while continuing to count up in seconds while holding the space bar, and reset to 0 then start counting up again when I release the space bar.

Currently I am struggling to get my stopwatch (what I called `timer()`) to reset to 0 whenever I press spacebar or release it.

Below is the code I have tried.

```
#install.packages("lubdridate")
#install.packages("shiny")
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(hr(),
                tags$script('
                            $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
                            Shiny.onInputChange("space_down", e.which == 32);
                            });'
                ),
                ## keyup
                tags$script('
                            $(document).on("keyup", function (e) {
                            Shiny.onInputChange("space_released", e.which == 32);
                            });'
                ),
                tags$hr(),
                textOutput('stopwatch')
                
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Initialize the stopwatch, timer starts when shiny app opens.
  timer <- reactiveVal(0)
  update_interval = 0.01 # each interval increases the timer by one hundrendth of a second 
  
  # Output the stopwatch.
  output$stopwatch <- renderText({
    paste("Time passed: ", seconds_to_period(timer()))
  })
  
  # observer that invalidates every second. Increases timer by one update_interval.
  observe({
    invalidateLater(10, session)
    isolate({
        timer(round(timer()+update_interval,2))
    })
  })
  # observers for Keys == 32 (Spacebar)
  observeEvent(input$space_down, {timer(0)})
  observeEvent(input$space_released, {timer(0)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)






#####Code which solves my problem!!######


library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)
library(keys)

my_options <- options(digits.secs = 3) 

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = NULL,
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
  lang = NULL,
  hr(),
  tags$script(HTML('document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
                                 if (!e.repeat) {
                                 Shiny.setInputValue("start", e.key == 32, {priority: "event"});
                                 }
                                  }
                                 );
                                  ')),
  tags$script(HTML('document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
                                 if (!e.repeat) {
                                 Shiny.setInputValue("reset", e.key == 32, {priority: "event"});
                                 }
                                 }
                                 );
                                  ')),
  tags$script(HTML('document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
                                 Shiny.setInputValue("stop", e.key == 83, {priority: "event"});
                                 }
                                 );
                                  ')),
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Tail Flick Latency StopWatch"),
    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarPanel(
      textOutput('stopwatch'),
      ),
  
  tags$hr(),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("TailFlickTrials")
      )
    )


#create data frame with 0 rows and 5 columns
v <- reactiveValues()
v$df <- data.frame(Trial_Date = character(), Start_Time = numeric(), End_Time = numeric(), 
           TimeLapsed = numeric(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  start_timing <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
  
  tmp_Trial_Date <- character()
  tmp_Start_Time <- numeric(0)
  tmp_End_Time <- numeric(0)
    
  # observeEvent for the keydown event
  observeEvent(input$start,{
    start_timing <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
    # on keydown event erase values of tmp_End_Time and tmp_Time_Lapsed previous saved
    tmp_End_Time <- numeric(0)
    # on keydown add one to tmp_Trial
    # on keydown, input new values for tmp_Trial, tmp_Trial_Date, and tmp_Start_Time        
    tmp_Trial_Date <- Sys.time()
    tmp_Start_Time <- Sys.time()
    # append tmp_Trial, tmp_Trial_date, tmp_Start_time to df
    # this method allows for the new row to have NA values for the End_Time and TimeLapsed columns. the code below will append those values to the row. 
    new_row <- head(v$df[NA,], 1)
    new_row[c('Trial_Date', 'Start_Time')] <- list(Trial_Date = tmp_Trial_Date, Start_Time = tmp_Start_Time)
    v$df <- rbind(v$df, new_row)
  })
  
  # observeEvent for the keyup event
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    start_timing <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
    # on keyup event erase values of tmp_Trial_Date, and tmp_Start_Time, previously saved
    tmp_Trial_Date <- character()
    tmp_Start_Time <- numeric(0)
    new_row <- head(v$df[NA,], 1)
    # on keyup, input new values for tmp_End_Time and tmp_Time_Lapsed
    tmp_End_Time <- Sys.time()
    tmp_TimeLapsed <- round(as.numeric(difftime(tmp_End_Time, v$df[nrow(v$df), 2], units ="secs")),3)
    # on keyup, combine tmp_End_Time and tmp_TimeLapsed into new vector called tmp
    # append tmp_End_Time and tmp_Time_Lapsed to df's last row by called nrow() in the row and the last two columns. 
    v$df[nrow(v$df), 3] <- tmp_End_Time
    v$df[nrow(v$df), 4] <- tmp_TimeLapsed
  })
  
  output$stopwatch <- renderText({
    as.numeric(Sys.time(), invalidateLater(100, session)) - start_timing
  })

  output$TailFlickTrials <- DT::renderDataTable({
    v$df
    })
  
  }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to us `Shiny.setInputValue` instead of `Shiny.onInputChange` as shown below.

```
ui <- fluidPage(hr(),
                # tags$script('
                #             $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
                #             Shiny.onInputChange("space_down", e.which == 32);
                #             });'
                # ),
                ## keyup
                # tags$script('
                #             $(document).on("keyup", function (e) {
                #             Shiny.onInputChange("space_released", e.which == 32);
                #             });'
                # ),
                
                tags$script(HTML('
                                 document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
                                 Shiny.setInputValue("space_down", e.key, {priority: "event"});
                                 });
                            ')),
                
                tags$script(HTML('
                                 document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
                                 Shiny.setInputValue("space_released", e.key, {priority: "event"});
                                 });
                            ')),
                tags$hr(),
                textOutput('stopwatch')
                
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But this doesn't solve my issue. My real issue is my code is reading each repeat key as a new keydown event.

Comment: Edit I am attempting to implement GiantBooley's answer to this question here but cannot make it work in shiny: How can I avoid autorepeated keydown events in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

@YBS has the good point: you have to use `Shiny.setInputValue` with the option `{priority: "event"}`, otherwise the observer does not react if `input$space_down` takes the same value as the previous one.

But this JS code will also trigger an event when *any* key is pressed (even if the event value is `FALSE`, this reacts). So you have to use:

```js
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
  if(e.which == 32) {
    Shiny.setInputValue("space_down", true, {priority: "event"});
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But this doesn't solve my issue. My real issue is my code is reading each repeat key as a new keydown event.

Comment: Edit I am attempting to implement GiantBooley's answer to this question here but cannot make it work in shiny: How can I avoid autorepeated keydown events in JavaScript?