# Listening for keyboard events (keyup/keydown): Why does this conditional statement not work on Mac OS browsers?

Tags: javascript, macos, events, web-audio-api

I have an open source project that is a music machine. In its simplest form, press a note on your keyboard and the app will play a predefined note.

Within the app I have an event listener waiting for a `keydown` event

Within the key down handler function there is a very simple conditional `if` statement that checks if the key being pressed has already been pressed but not released. It does this by checking for the existence of an oscillator running at a specific frequency, which is stored in an object literal e.g `{440: osc}`

Here's the if statement:

```
if (freq && !runningOscs[freq]) {
    // play a note at freq
  }
```

Without this conditional statement, if the user presses and holds a key, the note is played in rapid succession, which is unwanted in this instance.

Everything seemed fine until I came across folks having problems on the Mac OS, on this platform, the note is played in rapid succession as if the the conditional check isn't even there.

I'm at a loss with the Mac at he moment. I've fixed a few things so far, such as the combination key press ALT+Z where I needed to check if the omega (Ω) key was being pressed in order to run a specific function, but that's another story!

If anyone can shed any light onto why this might not work on Mac I would be most grateful. I think this is my last ditch attempt before I say "Sorry Mac O' it no workee"

OK!, So I've broken my app down to the bare minimum in order to isolate the problem and I can see nothing I can do to resolve the issue.

I've tested on just about every browser / Mac Os combination using browserstack.com but it seems all treat the code in the same way: Just ignore it!

Here's a little test Ive put together to demonstrate the issue:

```js
console.log("Yo! There! Mac O'");
// We have a crappy problem where our app doesn't
// work properly on Mac OS browsers, surprise!
// here we is just tryin to figure out why!

// The If statement's conditional seems to be ignored
// This is the critter:
/* 
    if (freq && !runningOscs[freq]) {
  playNote(freq);
  console.log(runningOscs);
}
*/

// `freq` is a variable holding the particular musical frequency
// mapped to the keyboard key being pressed by the user
// `runningOscs` is an object literal that holds currently playing
// oscillators and the frequency which that oscillator is set to e.g. 440Hz
// `playNote()` is a function that plays a note! LOL! it also copies the freq
// and oscillator to the `runningOscs` object


// ****** THE TEST ****** \\

// instantiate the audio context
const audioCTX = new AudioContext();

const freq = 440; // set the osc frequency
let runningOscs = {}; // object for running oscillators

function playNote(freq) {
  // create an oscilator
  const osc = audioCTX.createOscillator();
  osc.frequency.value = 220; // freq of osc
  osc.type = "sine"; // wave type for oscillator

  // gain node
  const vol = audioCTX.createGain();
  vol.gain.value = 1;

  // copy oscillator to runningOscs
  runningOscs[freq] = osc;
  console.log(runningOscs);

  // create the audio graph
  runningOscs[freq].connect(vol).connect(audioCTX.destination);

  // start the oscillator
  runningOscs[freq].start();
}

// event listeners
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyupHandler, false);

// key handlers
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  console.log(e.repeat); // is key being held down?
  if (e.repeat) return; // if so, return
  if (freq && !runningOscs[freq]) {
    playNote(freq);
    console.log(runningOscs);
  }
}

function keyupHandler(e) {
console.log("key up!");
  if (freq && runningOscs[freq]) {
    runningOscs[freq].stop();
    delete runningOscs[freq];
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<p>press a key to play a note</p>
<p>holding the key down</p>
<p>should play only one instance</p>
```

**EDIT** from the link in James' comment below I added:

`console.log(e.repeat); // is key being held down? if (e.repeat) return; // if so, return`

which returns a boolean value `true` if the key is being held down else `false`. This looked a cheap and cheerful way to overcome the problem, however, testing this (using browserstack) on Mac OS Ventura with Chrome browser v110 `e.repeat` returns `false` even while the key is being held down.

Comment: I'm on an M1 MacBook Pro and I do not experience the behavior you describe.

Comment: @Pointy I'm also on an M1 and I experience it. If I press and hold I get a continous note until I release. I'm using the latest Chrome.

Comment: I think we are to understand that the desired effect is the **continuous** note, and the undesired effect is the rapid succession of note *pulses*. My question is: might it be that on that specific device, not only the keydown event but also the keyup event is repeated while a key is down? Have you checked this?

Comment: Yes the desired effect is a continuous tone. I can't imagine why the keyup event would be fired until the key is released though??? I could console log the keyup event just to check if it is firing but hadn't thought of that being a possibility

Comment: I added the console.log to the keyup handler test

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with your _"key repeat"_ settings in System Preferences. I too only get a steady, single tone while the key is held down

Comment: @TimM. all object keys are stringified. Numbers are ok but they will become their `toString()` equivalent

Comment: @Barmar I think that's the *desired* behavior.

Comment: What's the difference between "the note is played in rapid succession" (which is undesired) and a continuous tone (which is desired)? That's what confused me.

Comment: @Phil I have key repeat enabled but I only get a continuous tone. I tried changing it from high frequency repeat to low frequency, there was no difference.

Comment: @Barmar _"What's the difference"_... beep!beep!beep!beep vs beeeeeeeeeeeeep. Changing "key repeat" settings didn't change my browser behaviour either. This is a very interesting question but obviously quite difficult to replicate

Comment: @trincot That was an inspirational thought to test if the keyup handler was being fired. Having tested that on browserstack's various browsers it is confirmed that the keyup handler is being triggered without the key being released by the user. Where to go from here?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686197/how-can-i-avoid-autorepeated-keydown-events-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

It might it be that on that specific device, not only the `keydown` event but also the `keyup` event is repeated while a key is down.

You confirmed in comments that this was actually happening on that device.

In that case I suggest this work-around:

Slightly delay the effect of a `keyup` event with a `setTimeout`. If this device will produce the next `keydown` event in quick succession, then that handler could cancel this timeout, so that the sound is not actually stopped. I don't know what the ideal delay would be for this, but it should be such that:

- It is great enough to allow the next repeated `keydown` event to occur in that time span
- It is small enough that it will not prevent a sound interruption from happening when the user really releases and presses the key in short succession.

In below implementation I put comments where I made changes (I removed your comments so that you can see where):

```js
let keyupTimer; // an ID returned by setTimeout
// Experiment with to following timeout. It should be as small as possible, 
// but still great enough to resolve the problem on the specific device.
const keyupDelay = 50; // time between keyup event and actual stop of sound

const audioCTX = new AudioContext();
const freq = 440;
let runningOscs = {};

function playNote(freq) {
  const osc = audioCTX.createOscillator();
  osc.frequency.value = 220;
  osc.type = "sine";

  const vol = audioCTX.createGain();
  vol.gain.value = 1;

  runningOscs[freq] = osc;
  console.log(runningOscs);

  runningOscs[freq].connect(vol).connect(audioCTX.destination);

  runningOscs[freq].start();
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyupHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  clearTimeout(keyupTimer); // abort the effect of a keyup that was triggered just before this event
  if (freq && !runningOscs[freq]) {
    playNote(freq);
    console.log(runningOscs);
  }
}

function keyupHandler(e) {
  clearTimeout(keyupTimer); // abort the effect of a previous keyup that was triggered just before this event
  // Delay the stop, so to allow a quick keydown event to cancel this from happening
  keyupTimer = setTimeout(() => { 
    if (freq && runningOscs[freq]) {
      runningOscs[freq].stop();
      delete runningOscs[freq];
    }
  }, keyupDelay);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<p>press a key to play a note</p>
<p>holding the key down</p>
<p>should play only one instance</p>
```

Comment: After some testing with this I found that it almost works. What I get at best is one short tone before the keyup event fires, then I get a continual tone until the key is released. I took some copies of the console logs from both Mac and PC but its a bit messy to paste them into here so I'll make an edit to the original question, when I get chance and post them in there with an explanation. I think the answer to my original question is that the conditional statement is not being ignored, it just that the `keyup` event is firing before the key is actually released. Another question to post?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest a new question. It would be good to include the different values for `keyupDelay` you have tried with, and how that influenced the results. I am not sure there is a perfect solution for this, as I can imagine you might even get different results on different Macs.

Comment: ".... might even get different results on different Macs" yep, that is my fear!

Comment: So you need to have access to all of them to see how they respond, and test.